# GitLab CI Templates - reference file/script local to the template

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Say I have a repo `ci-templates` with all my reused `gitlab-ci.yml` templates. I am trying to add a template that generates Release Notes based on the commits between tags. I generate the release notes with a bash script that lives in the `ci-templates` repo. The release job uses image `registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli` which uses `ash` by default but I can install `bash`, `git`, and a few other tools at the start.

How can I add a bash script in the `ci-templates` repo that is pulled in and used during other other CI jobs when the templates is used via

```
include:
  - project: 'ci-templates'
    file: 'templates/release-notes.yml'
```

I tried writing the bash script into the yml file, but `script:` is not executed as bash. Would I have to manually call bash on every single line? Is there no cleaner way?

I also tried using `$CI_JOB_TOKEN` and the files api to download the file from the repo and then run it via `bash script.sh` but this fails since the token does not have api permission to use the file api.

At this point, trying to make this a generic template is more pain than its worth. I'd be more productive just copy pasting the script everywhere, but I'd like to avoid that for the sake of my team. Any ideas here? I think I understand the yaml important, but I have no idea how to reference anything that lives outside of the yaml.

Answer (score 0):

In the template-ci yaml move the bash script to a job in the release-notes.yml

```
generate-release-notes:
  script:
    - echo "do something"
    - echo "done"
```

Then when you include that template into your repo that job will be executed. If you need to customize the behavior of the script use the "variables" section of the job

Comment: That works in this case because I can add `bash -c "cmd"` to ensure that it is run in bash. What about in general though? What if I want to run a python script, is there an idiomatic way to copy it over? Would my best bet just be echoing the source into a file and then running that?

Comment: Unless your runner is configured differently, bash is the default executor for the script section, so you shouldnt need the "bash -c".
An alternative could be to clone the template-ci repo then run the scripts.

Comment: Also you should beable to use the files api to download the file from the repo, but instead of the CI_JOB_TOKEN setup a access token for the template-ci repo https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html

Comment: thanks. I didn't think of setting up an access token. I guess I could do that and leave the token in the template so its available to those who need it. In response to the bash statement, the original question states the image being used and that bash is not the default shell

Comment: @Shatnerz I would suggest making it a hidden variable in the CI settings rather than as raw text in the ci